# Return a list of number to list of string

Tags: python, string, list

I want to return a list of number to a list of string:I have a list

```
copy=[[1,'a'],[55,'b'],[100,'c], [11,d],[66,f]]
```

if I have a list `code=[1,100,100,11,1,66,1]`
the result list must be like  the following list :
`['a','c','c','d','a','f','a']` then return it to a sequence `seq=['accdafa']`

It means , I compare each element in the list code with the element of the list copy.
for example I take the element `1` from code I compare it with the element of copy list
`code[0]=1`

```
 if code[0]==copy[0][0]:
                seq.append(copy[0][1])
             else:
                 go to the next element of the list 'copy'
```

I try the code:

```
for j in range(len(code)):

              if code[j]==copy[0][0]:
                seq.append(copy[0][1])
```

I get the following error :

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

the same thing for the rest of the element of the list `code`

Comment: yeah, look into dictinoaries. you'll find that it'll make your life a hell of a lot easier to use them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A perfect use for a [dict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict)!

```
copy = [[1, 'a'], [55, 'b'], [100, 'c'], [11, 'd'], [66, 'f']]
copy_as_dict = dict(copy)
code = [1, 100, 100, 11, 1, 66, 1]
seq = ''.join(copy_as_dict[i] for i in code)
```

The first element of each list item becomes the *key*, and the second becomes the *value*

Iterating over `code`, you grab the *value* from the dict for each *key* from `code`. Joining that by an empty string smooshes them together into one output, `'accdafa'`

Comment: OK. if the list code is `code=[[1,100,100,11,1,66,1] ,[66,1,100,66]]` and the `seq=[['accdafa'],['facf']]`